# Access variables inside a method

Tags: python

How can I get access to a variable inside a method outside the class?

```
class alpha(): 
    c = 9
    def __inobjectit__(self, k):
        self.k = k
    def amo(self):
        self.reward = 32
```

I know that to get access to the value of c outside the class I can simply use the following code:

```
a = alpha.c
```

But how can I get access to the value of the self.reward outside the class?

Comment: `__inobjectit__`? What?

Comment: `alpha().reward`?

Comment: It does not work Chayim. It returns " 'alpha' object has no attribute 'reward'"

Comment: `a = alpha();a.amo();a.reward`

Answer (score 0):

If you want (self.reward) to be a constant, you should put it in the **init** method, like this:

```
class alpha():
    def __init__(self,k):
        self.k = k
        self.reward = 32

a = alpha("Some argument")
value = a.reward
print(value)
```

Then if you want to change the value of .reward you do like this:

```
class alpha():
    def __init__(self,k):
        self.k = k
        self.reward = 32


a = alpha("Some argument")
value = a.reward
print(value)

a.reward = 10
value = a.reward
print(value)
```

Comment: You dont need functions to update class instance attributes. Nothing here is a constant